# How to authenticate an already logged in facebook user with facebook api

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am using facebook login in my codeigniter application. I have set up the controller to handle the login and it seems like it's working on all user-state cases except when the user is logged into facebook and is trying to log into my application but has never authenticated it.

Here is my facebook controller index function:

```
$data=array(
            'redirect_uri' => site_url('facebookcontroller/handle_facebook_login'),
            'scope' => 'publish_stream,email'
        );
        redirect($this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl($data));
```

Does ->getLoginUrl() direct only to the facebook login page but not the authentication page?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using an old version of the facebook sdk. I recommend taking a look [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src), as some of those functionalities are not working anymore.
then take into consideration that, when someone is logged into facebook and you ask for the profile info like this:

```
$data['user_profile'] = $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
```

It may be using an out of date access token, so you have to enclose that call in a try-catch block, like this:

```
try {
        $data['user_profile'] = $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
    }catch (Exception $e){
    $this->facebook->setAccessToken($this->facebook->getAccessToken());
    try {

       if($this->facebook->getUser()) {
        $this->facebook->api(array('method' =>'auth.revokeAuthorization' ));
       }

    }catch(Exception $e) {

        redirect('<login controller>');
    }
    redirect('<login controller>');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will try and see what i get, Now I have a new problem. It is working fine, but when I switch php run mode to fastcgi it stops working again, and does it gives me a 500 error with no details

Comment: you are very welcome :)    for that matter you can check here http://serverfault.com/questions/381872/why-would-i-get-a-500-internal-server-error-iis7-fastcgimodule-with-php    that could be a permissions problem